# how to find firefox plugin path in Linux

Tags: python, linux, firefox, selenium-webdriver, vnc-viewer

I need to put Firefox plugin path for Firefox profile which I am using.

```
profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile(plugin_path)
profile.set_preference("webdriver.load.strategy", "fast")
```

How to find Firefox plugin path in Linux so that I can pass the plugin_path on my python script

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you want to load plugin this way to `FirefoxProfile`? Docs have a different example:

```
File file = new File("firebug-1.8.1.xpi");
FirefoxProfile firefoxProfile = new FirefoxProfile();
firefoxProfile.addExtension(file);
firefoxProfile.setPreference("extensions.firebug.currentVersion", "1.8.1"); // Avoid startup screen

WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(firefoxProfile);
```

Anyway, plugins for Firefox are located in `~/.mozilla/firefox/MY_PROFILE/extensions`